# fetching nested object value

Tags: javascript, react-native, object

I have this code where it will log the value into the console

```
const table = { index: 0, 
data: {items:[ 
{students: {name: Gloria, age: 24, gender: female} , id: 025},
{students: {name: Alex, age: 27, gender: male} , id: 024}], 
total: 2}
} 

const result = table.data.items.map(Object.values);

console.log(result);
```

and the console will appear as

```
[[{name: Gloria, age: 24, gender: female} , 025],
[{name: Alex, age: 27, gender: male} , id: 024]]
```

The only problem is I want only the values to appear such as

```
[[{Gloria, 24, female}, 025],
[{Alex, 27, male}, 024]
```

can somebody tell me what is wrong in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this below

```
[[{Gloria, 24, female}, 025],
[{Alex, 27, male}, 024]
```

this object is not valid since Objects should have key-value pairs,

```
{Gloria, 24, female}
```

This below is valid

```
[[{name: Gloria, age: 24, gender: female} , 025],
[{name: Alex, age: 27, gender: male} , id: 024]]
```

or you can make it like this :

```
[[[Gloria, 24, female], 025],
[[Alex, 27, male], 024]
```

Do lemme know if this works, ill let you know how to do that

EDIT: ANSWER :

```js
const table = { index: 0, 
data: {items:[ 
{students: {name: "Gloria", age: 24, gender: "female"} , id: 25},
{students: {name: "Alex", age: 27, gender: "male"} , id: 24}], 
total: 2}
} 
/* 
[[[Gloria, 24, female], 025],
[[Alex, 27, male], 024] */

const result = table.data.items.map((data) => {
const newArr = [];
 newArr.push(data.id)
 const {age,gender,name} = data.students
 const secondArr = [name,age,gender];
newArr.push(secondArr)
return newArr
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: So how do I turn it into that?

Comment: which one? the last one?

Comment: Yeah for the [[[Gloria, 24, female], 025],
[[Alex, 27, male], 024]

Comment: @KisCoding you can check above

Comment: @KisCoding glad it helped: ) do upvote if you think it helped

Answer (score 0):

Can use `Array.map()` and **callback function** to achive that.
But will be a little differnet to this format

```js
[[{Gloria, 24, female}, 025],
[{Alex, 27, male}, 024]
```

example:

```js
const table = { 
  index: 0, 
  data: {
    items:[ 
      {students: {name: "Gloria", age: 24, gender: "female"} , id: 25},
      {students: {name: "Alex", age: 27, gender: "male"} , id: 24}], 
      total: 2}
} 

const result = table.data.items.map((x) => {
  let studentArray = [x.students.name, x.students.gender];
  
  return [studentArray, x.id];
});

console.log(result);
console.log(result[0]);
console.log(result[1]);
```